# "Who are they angry at - you or I" or "you or me"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case

Donald Trump at a charity dinner in NY last week said to Hillary Clinton:

> Who are they angry at? You or **I**.

German English schoolbooks teach "You and **me**" is right. Who is right? Does Trump use a more modern and more common form?

Comment: As far as I know, _you and I_ is the more formal version. _You and me_ is usually used by most people. If you really want to go to town grammatically you could rephrase the sentence to say _At whom are they angry?_. The whom is necessary, grammatically, but the preposition doesn't have to go at the start, that's more of a rumour than anything.

Comment: It should be "You or me." *Are they angry at I?* No. *They are angry at me.*

Comment: "Are you angry at I?" would sound very strange. I don't think adding "you" before "I" would make such a big difference.

Comment: Off-the-cuff remarks are often wrong, even including subconscious hypercorrection.

Comment: The quotation reads "you or I", not "you and I". It is WRONG. No-one would say "Are they angry at I?" It's quite simple to tell which to use in phrases like this by imagining that you leave out the other person mentioned.

Comment: Kids are often told to always say "you and I" as a way to correct sentences like "Me and you are going to the store." Unfortunately no one ever seems to realize that this is only true when "you and I' are the *subject* of the sentence! This hyper-correction leads to people, mostly native speakers, saying "you and I' even when "you and me" is correct. "You and I" is correct whenever you might say "we" or "I" (when the noun phrase is the subject) and "you and me" is correct whenever you might say "us" or "me" (when the noun phrase is an object). It's a common error but it really grates.

Comment: @N.Post That really bugs I too.

Comment: As a predicative complement, **I** is tolerable. As a complement of a preposition, it is not.